# Error while playing Unreal Tournament 2003

Tags: technical-issues, unreal-tournament-2003

I get the following error while playing Unreal Tournament 2003 on [my tablet](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01393369&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&lc=en&dlc=&cc=us&lang=&softwareitem=ob-77258-1&os=4062&dest_page=product&product=3653674) :

```
UT2003 Build UT2003_Build_[2002-09-19_17.26]
OS: Windows NT 6.1 (Build: 7600)
CPU: AuthenticAMD Unknown processor @ 1898 MHz with 2047MB RAM
Video: NVIDIA GeForce Go 6150 (9156)
Negative delta time!
UGameEngine::Tick <- UpdateWorld <- MainLoop
```

How can I prevent it?

Comment: Erm, what was the tag for this kind of posts?

Comment: troubleshooting is fine with me @badp

Comment: installed the AMD Dual-Core Optimizer, but it doesn't show on the tray in Windows 7 and the error still persists

Answer (score 2):

Negative delta time errors come from Windows misreading your processor speed or not recognizing it.  Since this is a game made in 2003, it won't have dual-core support, which is likely the cause of your problem.

If you have a dual-core CPU, this should help. Following [this thread on Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/194131-33-please-find-sollution), it looks like installing the AMD tool called [the AMD Dual-Core Optimizer](http://support.amd.com/us/Pages/dynamicDetails.aspx?ListID=c5cd2c08-1432-4756-aafa-4d9dc646342f&ItemID=153). This tool will help fix errors caused by a game not using the Windows API for timing.  This way of looking for a delta time is confused by dual-cores since there are two processors reporting their clock simultaneously.

If you don't have a dual-core CPU, then the problem gets a little hairier.  I would suggest installing the most up-to-date chipset drivers for your system, which might help with this problem. Also, make sure Windows is up-to-date, as there may have been a hotfix that prevents this from happening.

Comment: i've my tablet PC info, can you give more specific tips

Comment: If you give your information, I can see about tailoring an answer to your computer specs ...

Comment: just added it in the post as well : http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01393369&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&lc=en&dlc=&cc=us&lang=&softwareitem=ob-77258-1&os=4062&dest_page=product&product=3653674

Answer (score 0):

Running dual core optimizer will only help applications which are meant to run single-threaded benefit from both cores, but never be able to use both, only the utilization of both cores are kept in balance.

I guess the solution to your problem is the following:

(Quoting from http://hardanswers.net/unreal-tournament-dual-core)

1. Right click on the main game application. The location of this will vary from game to game.
   (..)* For Unreal Tournament 2003, this will be called UT2003.exe, (..)
2. Choose the Properties option.
3. Click on the Compatibility tab on the menu that appears.
4. Put a check mark in Run this program in compatibility mode.
5. In the drop box underneath choose Windows 98/Windows ME.